# pick random Ids already not picked from database

Tags: sql, database

Following are the methods i have already tried for picking random questions in Sql:

> select top 10 id from testTable order by newid()

- It is unoptimised for large data

> select top 10 id from testTable table sample(1 percent)
>    - But with table sample we cannot be sure that it will always return data as it works on probability of picking pages
>
> I have tried several other ways as taking the mod of row numbers but i still want more optimised solution

I want only those ids which are not picked earlier.
I don't want to use not in as sql doesn't cache not in query.

Any approach which is more optimised than using not in query for picking ids already not picked is welcomed.

I will discuss schema of tables:

suppose there are following tables:

1. table which is holding questions ,QuestionsTable
2. table holding all users for test say testUserTale
3. table containing questions for each user in test.

So i have to make sure student who has attempted question once should not see again in next test

Comment: What RDBMS?  Some may have better ways of dealing with this...

Comment: I would randomize the entire set of questions and put them in a table. All are "active" to start. Then select the top 10 active questions from that table, and mark them as "inactive" once done.

Comment: "I don't want to use not in as sql doesn't cache not in query." What does that mean? Do you want speed, or do you want correctness ?

Comment: How many questions do you have?  I just ran your original query on a table with 12k rows and it returned in roughly 1 second.  What performance are you aiming for?

Comment: i want performance when we use " not in " in sql query it does not cache the query plan.

Comment: there are 10000 users who will be giving test at a time.. so concurrently this query will be fired..

Comment: Please show us the "offending" query, and the table definitions. Also: your system will have to remember at least one bit of information ("has been used before") for every {user_id, question_id} tuple. That bit could be placed in a table that already has these fields as a candidate key, or it has to be located in a new table (where it would be redundant, because the existence of the keypair in that table could mean "has been used")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RANDOM Procedure

This procedure generates a random number (but see Usage Notes).

Syntax

DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
   RETURN binary_integer;

Pragmas

PRAGMA restrict_references (random, WNDS)
Return Values